# Is my code running in linear time? (O(n))

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, pointers

I am trying to create a program that identifies anagrams. Here is the prompt:

Two strings are anagrams if the letters can be rearranged to form each other. For example,
“Eleven plus two” is an anagram of “Twelve plus one”. Each string contains one ‘v’, three ‘e’s,
two ‘l’s, etc.
Write a program that determines if two strings are anagrams. The program should not be case
sensitive and should disregard any punctuation or spaces.

Notes:

1. Think how to break down your implementation to functions.
2. Pay attention to the running time of your program. If each input string contains n
   characters, an efficient implementation would run in a linear time (that is Θ(n)).

I am unsure if my code is running in linear time. What are some things I should be looking for to ensure that it is linear time?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const char SPACE = ' ';
const char PERIOD = '.';
const char COMMA = ',';
const char A = 'A';
const char Z = 'Z';
const char a = 'a';
const char z = 'z';

void letterArray(string line, int i, int*& letterCount) {
    if(line[i] >= a && line[i] <= z) {
        letterCount[line[i] - a]++;
    } else if (line[i] >= A && line[i] <= Z) {
        letterCount[line[i] - A]++;
    }
}

bool isAnagram(int*& arr1, int*& arr2) {
    bool anagram = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if(arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
            anagram = false;
        }
    }
    return anagram;
}

int main() {
    string line1;
    string line2;
    int * letterCount1 = new int[26];
    int * letterCount2 = new int[26];
    getline(cin, line1);
    getline(cin, line2);
    for(int i = 0; i < line1.length() || i < line2.length(); i++) {
        letterArray(line1, i, letterCount1);
        letterArray(line2, i, letterCount2);
    }
    if(isAnagram(letterCount1, letterCount2) == true) {
        cout<<"These two strings are anagrams."<<endl;
    } else (
        cout<<"These two strings are not anagrams."
    );
    delete[] letterCount1;
    delete[] letterCount2;
}
```

Comment: FYI, i'm pretty new to C++ and algorithm analysis. Thanks!

Comment: You could time it for different `n` and graph the result. Example of timing: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/steady-clock-struct?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/steady-clock-struct?view=msvc-170) If you do this be careful to get the input and output  out of the part you time.

Comment: A side note: consider to use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays in C++ (or `std::array` for static ones).

Comment: BTW - you have a bug: if e.g. `line1` is longer than `line2`, your `for` loop in `main` will call `letterArray` with an out-of-bounds index for `line2` due to the condition: `i < line1.length() || i < line2.length()`.

Comment: Work out how many operations your code does for a 5 character string, then do the same for 10 characters, does the number of operations double or more than double? If the former then the algorithm is linear (you'll actually need more than 2 days points to prove this but you get the idea)

Comment: You left out the `&` on the only parameter where it matters.

Comment: Separating the letter-counting of each line into its own loop does not affect the time complexity and would fix a bug. And your counting arrays are never initialized.

Comment: It would be easier to think about if you had a function that counts the letters in an entire string instead of passing a magic index from outside. Then that function is clearly linear in the string length. Calling it a constant number of times does not affect that complexity, only the lengths of the strings do.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not linear because you are making a copy of the line string everytime you call those functions -> quadratic. Use `const std::string& line` to avoid the copy. Then I think it is linear.

Some thoughts:

- Pass the character to `letterArray` directly, instead of passing the array + index. The less the function knows about the calling context, the simpler and more general it becomes.
- Do not use raw `new`, just use `std::vector`, use `std::array` if the size is know at compile time and you care about the allocations.
- `isAnagram` is really testing equality of two arrays, something that `std::vector` would do for you with `==`. `std::equal` can be used for the raw arrays you have.
- `line1.length() || i < line2.length()` you want `&&` there, otherwise you get out of bounds access. Yes, you have to finish processing the longer string after the loop. But why put the two calls in single loop in the first place? They are independent of each other. I would suggest `processLine` function that constructs the character count array and returns it instead.
- `isAnagram(letterCount1, letterCount2) == true` sure you can be explicit, but since you have chosen a good name for the function, `==true` is redundant here.

> What are some things I should be looking for to ensure that it is linear time?

Well, you can just measure its execution time as the commenters say. That is often what you are trying to optimize for anyway. But in general, you are looking for loops and the execution time of all functions you call.